# How to stop a Socket serve_forever thread python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets

I've looked everywhere on Stack overflow and I have not a seen a  questions directly related to what I'm trying to do. 
I'm currently trying to write a server that generates a thread on every query and then discards the thread once the query is complete. I been reading as many thread questions as I find, but the only answers I've found suggest closing the socket server which I do not think would work in my case. This example only has a single thread but imagine that there are n number of them. They would be spawned on query and since they are on server_forever they are basically memory leaks. I'm fairly new to threading in Python, and I I've tried to initialize the thread without serve_forever, but I get the following:

```
AttributeError: ThreadingUDPServer instance has no __call__ method
```

How do I either stop a serve_forever thread or how do I instantiate a thread without using serve_forever while keeping the target call I have? I've read most of the documentation on threading in the Python guides but none of them seem to address the serve_forever function on threading.

```
myController = Controller.Controller()
servers = [SocketServer.ThreadingUDPServer(('', 53), myController.UDPRequestHandler),]
thread = threading.Thread(target=servers[0].serve_forever)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
print 'UDP server loop running in thread: %s' % (thread.name)
    try:
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stderr.flush()
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Why would a call to `shutdown` not be acceptable? This only affects each SocketServer instance.

Comment: Let me try that and I will get back to you. From my understanding I thought it closed the socket entirely except for existing connections. Worth a try.

Comment: Why would you spawn a new socket server for incoming connection? I'm a little confused.

Comment: The socket server can run in one thread (main thread is fine). Each connection can spawn a worker thread that has absolutely nothing to do with the socket server.

Comment: I think we should approach this as a "just because you can't doesn't mean you should". Resources are finite and to spawn a thread for each individual request could run into a resource starvation problem. I think it may actually be better to instead create a pool of threads and then have a queue of tasks, this way you have a constraint on how you process requests. As for your service socket approach, I think you need  to explain your design a little more before we can actually truly understand your design/intentions. Specifically how your server connection relates to your worker threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the code and studying the properties of threads I've come to realize that the socket is kept open until the Daemon is terminated. The issue I listed here is already taking care of since the thread is daemonized and can be terminated by the program. If the thread was not daemonized then it would not be terminated and would actually serve_forever. Server_shutdown works to help clean up after the thread has been stopped.